# Test Class for LightningURIEvent Batch Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I wrote the following batch class to update a custom object when users view a record, this is for leadership reporting. The test class is throwing the error " A callout was unsuccessful because of pending uncommitted work related to a process, flow, or Apex operation. Commit or roll back the work, and then try again."

What is the proper way to test something like this?

```java
public class AuditTrailTrackerBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

   public Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       //The Datetime variables below are to ensure we get only data that is 1-60 minutes old. -1 denotes 1 hour ago
       DateTime dt = System.Now().addHours(-1);
       DateTime dtNow = System.Now();
       //Query should only get yesterday's data. We are unable to groupby using this object so the logic will be handled in the do while loop to sum the duration
      return [select id, Duration, RecordId, UserId, EventDate, QueriedEntities from LightningUriEvent WHERE EventDate >= :dt AND eventdate < :dtNow LIMIT 50000];
   }

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<LightningUriEvent> scope){
       //List to hold all records to insert
       List<Record_Audit__c> newAuditRecords = new List<Record_Audit__c>();
       //Using a traditional for loop in order to check the previous values to prevent duplicate records 
       //for(Integer i = 0; i < scope.size(); i++){
       for(LightningUriEvent lue : scope){
               Record_Audit__cauditRecord = new Record_Audit__c();
               //Cannot filter this value from SOQL so it is done here
               //Need to confirm the account values 
               if(lue.QueriedEntities == 'FinServ__FinancialAccount__c' ||lue.QueriedEntities == 'Account'){
                   Decimal durationInSeconds = lue.Duration / 1000;
                   //assigning the record type based on queried Object - The only two options coming through should be the same as above: Financial Account and Account
                   Id recordType = lue.QueriedEntities == 'Account' ? Schema.SObjectType.Record_Audit__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Account').getRecordTypeId() : Schema.SObjectType.Record_Audit__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Financial_Account').getRecordTypeId();
                   //Constructing record
                   auditRecord.RecordTypeId = recordType;
                   auditRecord.Record_View_Date_Time__c = lue.EventDate;
                   auditRecord.View_Time__c = durationInSeconds;
                   auditRecord.Viewed_Account__c = lue.QueriedEntities == 'Account' ? lue.RecordId : null;
                   auditRecord.Financial_Account__c = lue.QueriedEntities == 'FinServ__FinancialAccount__c' ? lue.RecordId : null;
                   auditRecord.Viewer__c = lue.UserId;
                   newAuditRecords.add(auditRecord);
               }           
       }
       insert newAuditRecords;
   }

   public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       
   }
}
```

```java
@isTest(SeeAllData=True)
public class GESA_AuditTrailTrackerBatchTest {
    @isTest
    static void testGESA_AuditTrailTrackerBatch(){
       //SF has a limitation on inserting LightningUriEvent records, so the test will check live data via SeeAllData=True.
       //Checking the record type as part 
       DateTime dt = System.Now().addHours(-1);
       Test.startTest();
        Id thisBatchId = Database.executeBatch(new GESA_AuditTrailTrackerBatch());
       Test.stopTest();
        
        Assert.isTrue(thisBatchId != null);
    }
```